# How to stop Jetty server from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty

I am using Eclipse with Maven. In my pom file i used following Jetty plugin to use as a deployment server. Now I have two problem

1. I can run this Jetty Server from Run As > Maven Build... > jetty:run
   But I do now know how to stop this server. After closing Eclipse if i go to http://localhost:8080. then i see this jetty server still running.
2. After deploying first project, if I start to work with second project then i can not deploy my second project on jetty. I followed the same process as before, but it does not work.

Note: I am a new user of Maven and Jetty

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.10</version>
        <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>                      
        </configuration>        
</plugin>
```

Comment: How do you deploy your second project on jetty? If you have the same set of rules in your 2nd project, that means your're attempting to run two jetty instances on port 8080. BTW, as to your question in title: `mvn jetty:stop` fails for you (see also manual for `stopPort` and `stopKey`)?

Comment: May be dma_k has a misunderstanding. Actually, what I did? First I created one project then using maven with jetty plugin and deploy. After deploy I close everything. But I saw in my web browser I can still access my localhost:8080. because jetty is still running with my project. OK, then, i run eclipse and create one new project with new maven with jetty plugin. But, problem is whenever i deploy this project with the command jetty:run. Then i saw my jetty server is still running with my previous project. This is may be because of, i did not stop jetty server before.(But i am not sure)

Comment: By the way. I solved my problem. after a little searching i got run-jetty-run (http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/) for eclipse. everything is very easy with it. After using this one i can say this is better then the jetty plugin in maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way. I solved my problem. after a little searching i got [run-jetty-run](http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/) (http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run) for eclipse. everything is very easy with it. After using this one i can say this is better then the jetty plugin in maven.

Comment: and for those wondering, to stop "Run Jetty Run" from inside Eclipse, simply go to the Console, type "q", then hit enter, and that'll stop it. You can also restart it with "r", as detailed here: http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/issues/detail?id=64#c3

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the Jetty server in the Maven Plugin, easily, no need to install more software.

1) Open the console (the panel usually docked on the right hand side of Eclipse)
2) Click Red Square (the Stop Button) for every Jetty Instance that is running

Comment: You can also use maven goal jetty:run to start and jetty:stop to stop